# Better ratio calculation 100:121 -> 1:1.21

Tags: javascript

I'm calculating some values and I'm using the following code to produce ratios (1:2, 2:5, etc.):

```
    var gcd,col1Sum = 100,col2Sum = 121;
    function calcGcd (a, b) {
        return (b == 0) ? a : calcGcd(b, a%b);
    }
    gcd = calcGcd(col1Sum, col2Sum);
    console.log(col1Sum / gcd +':'+ col2Sum / gcd);
```

In this example, it is producing some technically correct, but ugly ratios (e.g. 100:121). I'm trying to find a way to produce ratios with decimals given any size value. So, in the example above I'd like to be able to produce 1:1.21 rather than 100:121. I've thought about using the length of the ratios and dividing after the ratio is calculated but that seems quite inelegant, is there a more math-y way to do this?

Comment: `var min = Math.min(col1Sum, col2Sum); var r1 = col1Sum / min, r2 = col2Sum / min;` ?

Comment: Kind of defeats the purpose of finding the greatest common denominator first.

Comment: @zerkms, that does it. So simple, I was just having a brain-block day, I guess. If you add it as answer I'll select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have any other complex requirements, then simply

```
var min = Math.min(col1Sum, col2Sum);

var r1 = col1Sum / min,
    r2 = col2Sum / min;
```

must work.